# How can I pick randomly between a minus and plus sign?

Tags: c#, random

I'm making a math game, and I need to make it randomly pick between`-` or `+`.
I have already tried this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string name = rnd.Next(-, +);
```

But that doesn't work. Anyone have a way I can do this?

Comment: Well, look at what methods `Random` *does* provide. Hint: if you got a random number that was 0 or 1, could you convert that to `'-'` or `'+'`?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: That barely qualifies as an attempt in my opinion, even ignoring the list of overloads of `Random.Next`, there is just no way that syntax could ever work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T NextItem<T>(this Random r, params T[] items)
    {
        //  Thanks to nbokmans for catching my error here: The second parameter
        //  is not the largest value it can return; it's the "exclusive upper bound".
        return items[r.Next(0, items.Length)];
    }
}
```

...

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string name = rnd.NextItem("-", "+");
```

Comment: Perhaps some context on extension methods. If the op is asking to randomize two strings, surely he wouldn't have a clue where to put the extension method. +1 though anyhow.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that expression bodied methods are a C# 6 thing, but I'd like to think that everybody is running a version of visual studio >= 2013

Comment: We'd all love to think that. However............ I've seen some shit man. I've seen some shit. ;)

Comment: Good point, changed to C#5 usage. @Cory What, have you been peeking at my desktop again?

Comment: Wouldn't this always exclude the item at the last index of `items`? Considering the upper bound of `Next` function is exclusive.

Comment: @nbokmans The second parameter is `maxValue`, max index in a zero-indexed array is `a.Length - 1`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett but the `Next` function upper bound parameter is exclusive, so if you pass an array of 10 items, and do `r.Next(0, array.Length)` or `r.Next(0, 10)`, it would still only return a number in the range of 0 to 9 (i.e. the array's bounds).

Comment: @nbokmans You are, of course, absolutely correct. I should have tested the code. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 6):

As a commenter mentioned the `Random` class does not let you generate a random letter. However, it does offer a random number generation function: `Next()`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

So, to generate a random `+` or `-` becomes really trivial with that - we just create an array containing the possible options, and generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array. You might think, but wait, if my array contains 2 items, and the random number is 2, and I try to access the array at index 2, wouldn't I get an index out of bounds exception? The answer to that is no, because the upper bound is exclusive in the `Next()` function - it can return anything between 0 and `upperBound - 1`.

```
char[] options = {'+', '-'};
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, options.Length);
char randomChar = options[randomNumber];
```

Comment: Frustrating - Edits must be at least 6 characters. `options.Length + 1` should be `options.Length - 1`. This gets my upvote, it's short - simple and easy to follow.

Comment: Length returns the actual count which would be 2, but arrays are zero indexed, so `options.Length - 1` would return a number from 0 to 1 which is our intended behavior, + is index 0 and - is index 1 in your `options` array.

Comment: @ColinM but the upper bound is exclusive, so even if you do `rnd.Next(0, options.Length)` which is the same as `rnd.Next(0, 2)`, wouldn't it still guarantee you would be within the bounds of the array?

Comment: You're right, my apologies. `Next` will only return 0 or 1 here with the Length as is.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using LINQ:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int count = 10;
    char[] plusesAndMinuses = new int[count]
        .Select(i => random.Next())
        .Select(i => i % 2 == 0 ? '+' : '-')
        .ToArray();

    string result = new string(plusesAndMinuses);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string value = "";

switch (rnd.Next(0, 2))
{
    case 0:
        value = "+";
        break;
    case 1:
        value = "-";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Random.Next()` will return random `integer` value. Based on that you can distinguish if it should be `+` or `-`. Example :

```
Random random = new Random(); // new Random object
int randomValue = random.Next(); // get new random value
int oneOrZero = randomValue % 2; // get either 1 or zero
string name = "";
if ( oneOrZero == 0 ) // if value is zero
{
    name = "-"; // name will contain minus sign
}
else 
{
    name = "+"; // else name will contain plus sign
}
```

You can simplify this to just one line :

```
string name = new Random().Next() % 2 == 0 ? "-" : "+";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to flip a coin to get either a positive or a negative number? If you just want a string that's either + or - try this:

```
string name = (rnd.NextDouble() > 0.5)? "+" : "-";
```

Then you can concatenate if that is what you are trying to do:

```
name = name + rnd.Next(); // Or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    String[] symbols = new[]{"-", "+"};
    Random r = new Random();
    var sym = symbols[r.Next(0, 2)];
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VaC9II)