# Select a Random Color from a List

Tags: c#, random, colors, generator

How can I make a random color generator, but only using 5 colours that I choose for my program.
Im doing a priority system that uses colors to attribute to each pacient at an hospital.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried to put the color name in an array and choose a random index for it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i generate a random string that can contain either plus sign or minus sign (- or +)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851416/how-can-i-generate-a-random-string-that-can-contain-either-plus-sign-or-minus-si)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695187/pick-random-string-from-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this simple example:

```
static Color[] colors = { Color.Red, Color.Green... };
static Color GetRandomColor()
{
    var random = new Random();
    return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
}
```

And don't forget `using System.Drawing`.

Comment: Thanks, simple and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
// Define your colors array
string[] colors = { '#4FC1E9' , '#FE424D', '#1AA6B7', '#967ADC', '#48cfad' };

// Get a random index
Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.Next(colors.Length);

string randomColor = ((string)colors[r]);
```

Comment: I just updated, that was for `Collection`.